# How to convert digital signal to analog value

Tags: analogread, digital-analog-conversion

I have spwm output from arduino, and when i read on analogread it shows only 1023 and 0, because it is digital signal. 
Is there any way to convert these spwm value into analog value reading

Comment: arduino had 10 bit ADC that means maximum value that you can read is 0-1023. It is an analog signal. or if you want to convert digital value into analog value use can DAC IC easily available in the market.

Comment: Thanks try to search it

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be clear to you: for slow systems a pwm signal can be considered analog, but measuring at higher rates and without a filter reveales the digital nature behind pwm and all you see is either logic high (1023) or low (0).
Possible solutions are:

1. apply a filter in hardware (LC low-pass)
2. apply a filter in software (e.g. by calculating a running mean)
3. attach interrupts to the rising/falling edge of your signal and measure the high/low time to calculate the duty cycle

Which of those options to choose will mainly depend on the PWM frequency you want to measure. For low frequency I recommend option 3 (special cases are duty cycles around 0% and 100% as there are no edges), for higher frequencies I would use option 1/2.

Comment: Thanks very much helping